# How to concatenate /append 2 strings in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I am trying to concatenate an `Int` with a `String` such that the output is a `String` but not sure how to go about it.

Here's my code so far:

```
val myMessage = context.getString(R.string.mymessage)
```

where `myMessage` is a String.

Now I want to append an Int which is `it.myinfo.codeid`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates):

```
"${context.getString(R.string.mymessage)} ${it.myinfo.codeid}"
```

Comment: That’s the way to go

Comment: @Moira any idea about this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302694/how-do-i-detect-skype-telegram-whatsapp-calls-when-my-messenger-app-is-in-a-call

Answer (score 2):

**Concatenation in kotlin can be done in 3 ways**

**1 - Using String Templates**

```
val myMessage = "${context.getString(R.string.mymessage)} ${it.myinfo.codeid}"
```

**2 - Using + Sign**

```
val myMessage = context.getString(R.string.mymessage) + " " + it.myinfo.codeid
```

**3 - Using StringBuilder**

```
val sb = StringBuilder()
val myMessage = sb.append(context.getString(R.string.mymessage)).append(it.myinfo.codeid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `+` as known in Java:

```
context.getString(R.string.mymessage) + " " + it.myinfo.codeid
```

or use the more idiomatic templates approach:

```
"${context.getString(R.string.mymessage)} ${it.myinfo.codeid}"
```

Comment: any idea about this one : any idea about this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302694/how-do-i-detect-skype-telegram-whatsapp-calls-when-my-messenger-app-is-in-a-call